# why su root -c does not work for awk

Tags: linux

I tried to run the following command but it does not work.

```
su temproot -c "awk -F : '{print $1}' /tmp/test.log"
```

If I run `awk -F : '{print $1}' /tmp/test.log`, it will show:

```
item 
name 
age 
sex
```

This is expected result.
But if I run `su temproot -c "awk -F : '{print $1}' /tmp/test.log"`
the result will be:

```
item : 1
name : susan
age : 20
sex : female
```

Does the su -c cannot run awk sucessfully or something I write is incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: $1 is inside double-quotes so is expanded to the value of the 1st arg to the shell running it (probably the empty string as most other values would probably cause an awk syntax error or be treated as an empty/undefined awk variable)...so the awk script is actually just `{print}`.   Escape it as `\$1`.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful

Comment: I would have made that an answer but i'm pretty sure it's a dupe that i'm too lazy to go hunting for right now.    Quoting is a never-ending source of  shell-scripting problems (and questions here on U&L).  Quoting and whitespace-related issues.

Comment: ^both suggestions there could be used here (escape like @cas suggested, or use `su` only to get the file and pipe it to awk outside su, e.g., `su temproot -c 'cat /tmp/test.log' | awk ...`)